# Python Score Counter For Controlled Test

Tags: python

I have a controlled assessment in roughly seven hours that requires me to build a program that can keep score of a competition. In this competition there are 4 teams and 5 games. I need a program that will give 1 point to teams in the event of a tie, 2 points for a home win and 3 points for an away win. I also need it to display an error message or something when an incorrect team number has been entered. Can anyone help? It also needs to be in python.

I've only been coding for a few weeks and i have no idea what I'm doing. I am trying to figure out how to print out a statement when an incorrect team number is entered without it counting within the loop

My code so far:

```
schoolnumber = [1,2,3,4]
homescores =[0,0,0,0]
awayscores=[0,0,0,0]

for counter in range(0, 5):
    whohost = int(input("Who hosted the game? "))
    whowins = int(input("Who was the winner? "))
    if whohost == whowins:
        homescores[whowins-1] += 2
    else:
        awayscores[whowins-1] += 3

print(homescores)
print(awayscores)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow (SO)! You need to try and show your code attempts here when you are facing a more specific coding problem than you are asking right now. Asking others to code for you is not the way of SO..

Comment: I  have added as much code as I can remember

Comment: I am not sure whether there is one who might answer this soon, but my suggestion is: you need to pinpoint which part of your code is not behaving according to your expectation. Then, by telling your expected result, you might get quicker and more accurate answer there.

Comment: Indentation is very important in Python, and your code has none. If your code isn't work, I'd suggest writing it and *running* it to see what errors the interpreter might know.

Comment: My code is working but I am trying to figure out how to print out a statemnt when an incorrect team number is entered without it counting within the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for counter in range(0, 5):
    while True:
        try:
            whohost = int(input("Who hosted the game? "))
            whowins = int(input("Who was the winner? "))
            if whohost in schoolnumber and whowins in schoolnumber:
                break
            else:
                raise ValueError()
        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter a valid number from the list {}'.format(schoolnumber)) 
    if whohost == whowins:
        homescores[whowins-1] += 2
    else:
        awayscores[whowins-1] += 3
```

This will loop over the two `input` statements until both the numbers entered are in `schoolnumber`. If a number not in the list or a string is entered it will display the error message and start over.

Answer (score -1):

Okay the code should look like this (I don't know what sport it is, hope I didn't make mistakes)

```
MAX_SCHOOLS = 4
MAX_GAMES = 5

teams = [0]*MAX_SCHOOLS

for i in range(MAX_GAMES):
    host = int(input("Who hosted the game [1 to {}]? ".format(MAX_SCHOOLS)))
    winner = int(input("Who was the winner (0 for tie) ? "))
    away = int(input("Away team [1 to {}] ? ".format(MAX_SCHOOLS)))
    if winner == away:
        print("Error : Away team = Host team")
        continue # skip this game
    if not 0 <= winner < MAX_SCHOOLS:
        print("Error : winner incorrect")
        continue
    if not 0 <= host < MAX_SCHOOLS:
        print("Error : host incorrect")
        continue
    if not 0 <= away < MAX_SCHOOLS:
        print("Error : winner incorrect")
        continue
    if host == winner:
        teams[host-1] += 2
    elif away == winner:
        teams[away-1] += 3
    else:
        teams[away-1] += 1
        teams[host-1] += 1

print(teams)
```